# How to properly setup Spyder on macOS?

Tags: python, pip, spyder

So I installed Spyder with anaconda navigator while following an online python course. However, the teacher's copy seems to feature code completion and documentation and mine does not. I've tried typing pip install Spyder into the terminal to install any dependencies and pip install rope_py3k because another StackOverflow answer suggested doing so. However, my Spyder app still does not have autocompletion. How do I fix this?

Comment: What version of Spyder did you install? Code completion is inexplicably broken in Version 3.x, so they revamped it in V4

Comment: I'm using version 4.1.3!